# How to replace - with &ndash; using php

Tags: php, function, preg-replace, htmlspecialchars

How do i replace `-` with `&ndash;` using php `htmlspecialchars()`

`$content = $_POST['content'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't, `-` is not a special character and as such will not be touched by `htmlspecialchars()`. And `-` is not even same as `&ndash;` (- vs. –).

You can use `str_replace()` if you want to:

```
$content = str_replace('-', '&ndash;', $_POST['content']);
```

Answer (score 1):

[htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) will convert `–` to `&ndash;` (and take care of any other entities as well).

Just make sure you specify the correct character set, e.g.:

```
echo htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```